# Exception in thread "main" org.pdfclown.util.parsers.ParseException: 'name' table does NOT exist

Tags: java, parsing, pdf, importerror, pdfclown

I am trying to run the Java Code written by **Stefano Chizzolini** (Awesome guy : Creator of PDFClown) to **Parse a PDF** using PDF Clown library. I am getting this error and I dont know what I can do to fix this.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.pdfclown.util.parsers.ParseException: 'name' table does NOT exist.
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.OpenFontParser.getName(OpenFontParser.java:570)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.OpenFontParser.load(OpenFontParser.java:221)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.OpenFontParser.<init>(OpenFontParser.java:205)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.TrueTypeFont.loadEncoding(TrueTypeFont.java:91)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.SimpleFont.onLoad(SimpleFont.java:118)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.Font.load(Font.java:738)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.Font.<init>(Font.java:351)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.SimpleFont.<init>(SimpleFont.java:62)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.TrueTypeFont.<init>(TrueTypeFont.java:68)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.Font.wrap(Font.java:253)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.FontResources.wrap(FontResources.java:72)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.FontResources.wrap(FontResources.java:1)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ResourceItems.get(ResourceItems.java:119)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.objects.SetFont.getResource(SetFont.java:119)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.objects.SetFont.getFont(SetFont.java:83)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.objects.SetFont.scan(SetFont.java:97)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner.moveNext(ContentScanner.java:1330)
at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:626)
at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:296)
at PDFReader.FullExtract.run(FullExtract.java:71)
at PDFReader.FullExtract.main(FullExtract.java:142)
```

I know the class **OpenFontParser** in the library package is throwing this error. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

This code works for most PDF. I have a PDF that it does not parse. I am guessing it is because of [this symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF2pB.png) below in the pdf.

```
public class PDFReader extends Sample {

@Override
public void run()
{
    String filePath = new String("C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Desktop\\SomeSamplePDF.pdf");

    // 1. Open the PDF file!
    File file;
    try
    {file = new File(filePath);}
    catch(Exception e)
    {throw new RuntimeException(filePath + " file access error.",e);}

    // 2. Get the PDF document!
    Document document = file.getDocument();

    // 3. Extracting text from the document pages...
    for(Page page : document.getPages())
    {
    extract(new ContentScanner(page)); // Wraps the page contents into a scanner.

    }
    close(file);
}

private void close(File file) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/**
Scans a content level looking for text.
 */
/*
NOTE: Page contents are represented by a sequence of content objects,
possibly nested into multiple levels.
 */
private void extract(
        ContentScanner level
        )
{
    if(level == null)
        return;

    while(level.moveNext())
    {
        ContentObject content = level.getCurrent();
        if(content instanceof ShowText)
        {
            Font font = level.getState().getFont();
            // Extract the current text chunk, decoding it!
            System.out.println(font.decode(((ShowText)content).getText()));
        }
        else if(content instanceof Text
                || content instanceof ContainerObject)
        {
            // Scan the inner level!
            extract(level.getChildLevel());
        }
    }
}

private boolean prompt(Page page)
{
    int pageIndex = page.getIndex();
    if(pageIndex > 0)
    {
        Map<String,String> options = new HashMap<String,String>();
        options.put("", "Scan next page");
        options.put("Q", "End scanning");
        if(!promptChoice(options).equals(""))
            return false;
    }

    System.out.println("\nScanning page " + (pageIndex+1) + "...\n");
    return true;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    new PDFReader().run();
    }

}
```

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to post images yet. This is the link http://postimg.org/gallery/cf6rhk96/6d5fed2b/

Comment: Can you provide the PDF in question? The stack trace looks like there is an embedded font in it which PDFClown fails to parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The issue

As the stacktrace indicates, the problem is that some TrueType font embedded in the PDF does not contain a `name` table even though it is a required table:

```
org.pdfclown.util.parsers.ParseException: 'name' table does NOT exist.
...
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.TrueTypeFont.loadEncoding(TrueTypeFont.java:91)
```

Thus, strictly speaking, that embedded font is invalid and consequentially the embedding PDF, too. And PDFClown runs into an exception due to this validity issue.

### Some backgrounds

> A TrueType font file consists of a sequence of concatenated tables. ...
>
> The first of the tables is the font directory, a special table that facilitates access to the other tables in the font. The directory is followed by a sequence of tables containing the font data. These tables can appear in any order. Certain tables are required for all fonts. Others are optional depending upon the functionality expected of a particular font.
>
> Tables that are required must appear in any valid TrueType font file. The required tables and their tag names are shown in Table 2.
>
> Table 2: The required tables
>
> ```
> Tag     Table 
> 'cmap'  character to glyph mapping 
> 'glyf'  glyph data 
> 'head'  font header 
> 'hhea'  horizontal header 
> 'hmtx'  horizontal metrics 
> 'loca'  index to location 
> 'maxp'  maximum profile 
> 'name'  naming 
> 'post'  PostScript
> ```
>
> (Section *TrueType Font files: an overview* in chapter 6 *The TrueType Font File* in the *[TrueType Reference Manual](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TTRefMan/)*)

On the other hand, though, there are a number of PDF generators cutting down embedded TrueType fonts to the bare essentials required by PDF viewers (foremost Adobe Reader), and the `name` table does not seem to be strictly required.

Furthermore the table `name` is only used for one purpose in PDFClown, to determine the name of the font in question, even though the font name could be determined from the **BaseFont** entry of the associated font dictionary, too. Actually the latter entry is **required** by the PDF specification while the *PostScript name of the font* entry in the `name` table is **optional** according to the TTF manual.

Thus, using the **BaseFont** entry in the PDF font dictionary would be a better alternative to this `name` table access.

### Fixing it

> Is there anything I can do to fix this?

You can either fix the not entirely valid PDF by adding a `name` table to the embedded TTF in question or you can patch PDFClown to ignore the missing missing table: in the class [`org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.OpenFontParser`](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/clown/code/trunk/java/pdfclown.lib/src/org/pdfclown/documents/contents/fonts/OpenFontParser.java) edit the method `getName`:

```
private String getName(
  int id
  ) throws EOFException, UnsupportedEncodingException
{
  // Naming Table ('name' table).
  Integer tableOffset = tableOffsets.get("name");
  if(tableOffset == null)
    throw new ParseException("'name' table does NOT exist.");
```

Replace that `throw new ParseException("'name' table does NOT exist.")` by `return null`.

### PS

While the problem could be analyzed using merely the information given by the OP, the [sample file](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=3E7CF65957A3EFBF!575&authkey=!ABJSXfOLF2CKAJU&ithint=file,.pdf) provided by [@akarshad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/873174/akarshad) in his now deleted answer gave more motivation to start the analysis at all.

Comment: Excellent Answer! Thank you so much. That particular document, pdf in question, had some sensitive data that I could not post. But I was trying to find some document with similar attributes I could post without worrying about it. Anyway, this seems to resolve the issue! Thanks again! :)