# PDFClown NullPointerException in GlyphMapping

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, pdfclown

I recently switched my code from PDFClown v0.1.2 to v0.1.2.1. There were some differences which I think I have already met now (changed constructors of TextMarkup() and switching from CallOutNote to StaticNote) but unfortunately I've run in some troubles which I haven't figured out yet how to fix it.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.Encoding.put(Encoding.java:88)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.StandardEncoding.<init>(StandardEncoding.java:41)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.Encoding.<clinit>(Encoding.java:54)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.SimpleFont.getBaseEncoding(SimpleFont.java:82)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.SimpleFont.loadEncoding(SimpleFont.java:142)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.SimpleFont.onLoad(SimpleFont.java:170)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.Font.load(Font.java:878)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.Font.<init>(Font.java:368)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.SimpleFont.<init>(SimpleFont.java:65)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.TrueTypeFont.<init>(TrueTypeFont.java:47)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.Font.wrap(Font.java:262)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.FontResources.wrap(FontResources.java:72)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.FontResources.wrap(FontResources.java:1)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ResourceItems.get(ResourceItems.java:119)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.objects.SetFont.getResource(SetFont.java:119)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.objects.SetFont.getFont(SetFont.java:83)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.objects.SetFont.scan(SetFont.java:97)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner.moveNext(ContentScanner.java:1360)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner$TextWrapper.extract(ContentScanner.java:819)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner$TextWrapper.<init>(ContentScanner.java:771)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner$TextWrapper.<init>(ContentScanner.java:764)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner$GraphicsObjectWrapper.get(ContentScanner.java:684)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner$GraphicsObjectWrapper.access$0(ContentScanner.java:676)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ContentScanner.getCurrentWrapper(ContentScanner.java:1184)
at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:636)
at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:653)
at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:653)
at org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor.extract(TextExtractor.java:299)
at theproject.logic.WorkerThread.extractTextOfHighlight(WorkerThread.java:758)
at theproject.logic.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.GlyphMapping.load(GlyphMapping.java:69)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.GlyphMapping.<clinit>(GlyphMapping.java:47)
... 30 more
```

The method "extractTextOfHighlight()" extracts the text within a document which is highlighted:

```
protected List<ITextString> extractTextOfHighlight(Rectangle2D rect2d, Page page) {
    TextExtractor extractor = new TextExtractor();

    List<Rectangle2D> areas = new ArrayList<Rectangle2D>();
    areas.add(rect2d);
    extractor.setAreas(areas);
    extractor.setAreaTolerance(2.0);

    Map<Rectangle2D, List<ITextString>> map = extractor.extract(page);
    // Util.printExtractedTextMapToConsole(map);
    for(Rectangle2D keyRect : map.keySet()) {
        return validateExtractedStrings(map.get(keyRect));
    }

    return null;
}
```

There is a post on StackExchange which was the only one describing a similar error:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23804322

I already applied the recommended fix in PDFClown but ran into the same error. My question is, if there is anything I can do to fix this error. I'm really out of ideas.

Here is the pdf I used for my testing:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pt32s7gbrvr21a8/testfile.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please verify you have built your PDF Clown jar correctly.

Your exception initially occurs as a `NullPointerException`

```
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.GlyphMapping.load(GlyphMapping.java:69)
at org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts.GlyphMapping.<clinit>(GlyphMapping.java:47)
```

i.e. in `GlyphMapping.load` during

```
  glyphListStream = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
      GlyphMapping.class.getResourceAsStream("/fonts/AGL20.scsv")
      )
    );
```

the resource `"/fonts/AGL20.scsv"` could not be found (which causes `getResourceAsStream` to return `null` which the `InputStreamReader` constructor forwards to its parent class `Reader` constructor which compares its parameter with `null` and in case of equality throws an explicit `NullPointerException`).

Comment: Good point! Following your advice I tried to build it again using the ant file, resulting in the following error:


    Buildfile: /home/workspace/pdfclown.lib/build.xml

compile:
    [javac] /home/workspace/pdfclown.lib/build.xml:68: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds

package:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/workspace/pdfclown.lib/build/package

BUILD FAILED
/home/workspace/pdfclown.lib/build.xml:111: /home/main/res/pkg does not exist.

What am I missing?

Comment: In addition: after failing with the build I added the source code as library in my main project, resulting in the first mentioned error. Just to get it right: 1) download sources from SVN 2) right click on build.xml (Eclipse) > "Run As" > "Ant build" > Run should result in a file "build/package/pdfclown.jar", is this correct? Thank you for your kind help, @mkl!

Comment: I pulled the sources from SVN again, this time from my own home dir. Now the build worked like a charm and the error is gone now. I'm a little bit embarrassed but happy, that it works now. Keep up the excellent work, @mkl thank you very much!